# frozen frames detection openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to detect camera is capturing frozen frames or black frame. Suppose a camera is capturing video frames and suddenly same frame is capturing again and again. I spend long time to get any idea about this problem statement but i failed. So how we detect it or any idea/steps/procedure for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my approach to solve this issue.

Frozen frames: calculate absolute difference over HSV/RGB per every pixel in two consecutive frames np.arrays and determine max allowed diff that is valid for detecting frozen frames.

Black frames have naturally very low (or zero) V-value sum over the frame. Determine max V-sum of whole frame to determine, below which the frame is "black".

Comment: Frozen frames i have done using your above method. But for black frames how we determine max V-sum.

Comment: Convert image to HSV. ( with hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) ), extract v-channel (h, s, v = hsv_img[:, :, 0], hsv_img[:, :, 1], hsv_img[:, :, 2]).  Sum all pixel values of V channel ( v_sum = np.sum(h) ) in HSV and determine what is maximum you allow to be in the frame. Typically averaging less than 10-30/pixel is enough to determine "black". However, already small deviation to "proper lighting situation" might have considerable impact. So, if "proper conditions" average 125/pixel in V channel, then average <100/pixel could be too black already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple opencv method to detect black frame

```
if (cv::countNonZero(frame) == 0) 
{
    //do something if frame is black
}
```