# OpenCV find frozen frames in video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have been trying to look at a video in my library and detect frozen frames using python and `OpenCV`.

There is one [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493527/frozen-frames-detection-opencv-python) that had an answer, but I didn't quite understand the it. The answer is as follows:

> Frozen frames: calculate absolute difference over HSV/RGB per every pixel in two consecutive frames np.arrays and determine max allowed diff that is valid for detecting frozen frames.

What is the best way to detect frozen frames greater than 3 seconds in a video?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Get the framerate of the video. Say it is 24 fps. So your 3 seconds means you are looking for 72 consecutive frames where the difference between each frame and the next is very small.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I am specifically not understanding is how to "calculate the absolute difference between each frame."  I would appreciate any help you would have with that code or direction to some documentation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the absolute difference between two frames `Frame1` and `Frame2` you can use this:

```
Diff=np.sum(np.abs(Frame1-Frame2))
```

`np` is the short name for `numpy` which you should import at first by `import numpy as np`
`np.abs` is calculating the absolute value of each pixel in the difference `Frame1-Frame2` and obviously `np.sum` is summing all values so you end up with one value.

As for extending this to detect if the video is frozen for 3 seconds, you should do the above calculation either for each two "consecutive" images in the span of 3 seconds. Or calculate the difference between current frame and frame at current time - 3 seconds. Something like this:

```
time1=1000 #This is 1st second
time2=4000 #This is the 4th second

cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,time1) 
ret, Frame1= cap.read()

cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,time2)
ret, Frame2= cap.read()
```

`cap` is the video capture.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate your help and am trying this now.

Comment: I used the `Diff=np.sum(np.abs(Frame1-Frame2))` and it caught frames that were black (the difference was listed as 0) but on my test video of a freeze frame, I had it print the Diff and the numbers were all quite high
`Frame is 595
The difference is 6401303
Frame is 596
The difference is 12259330`

Is there something I am missing?  I can give more info and I am reading the documentation.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user3324136 What's the width and the height of the frames? better to divide by width*height so the numbers are normalized. In my opinion, the difference will not be a zero but a bigger number and so you need to define a threshold.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.